# Unable to debug some code ? Strange stack with MSVC?

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, boost, fseek

Sometimes I got a crash of my application with the following stack trace :

```
  atiocl.dll!0f6c463a()
  [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for atiocl.dll]
  atiocl.dll!0f2ed724()
  atiocl.dll!0f2ed82c()
  atiocl.dll!0f2ad8cb()
  OpenCL.dll!000a172c()
  pureStudio.exe!__fseeki64()  + 0xdec0 bytes C++
  pureStudio.exe!__fseeki64()  + 0x9b6f bytes C++
  pureStudio.exe!__fseeki64()  + 0x1f027 bytes C++
  msvcr90d.dll!5af8327f()
  ntdll.dll!77bb041d()
  ntdll.dll!77b79d45()
```

It is a memory access violation !
Unfortunately I have no idea of the problem...

For information I use VS 2008 + QT + BOOST + OpenCL

What is strange is that I know "where" the problem occur... I just have to remove a specific line of code... and no more error (But the soft doesn't do what it should :-P)

The call is on "my code" but this time I don't see my methods in the stack !!!! (I'm able to trace others code, other crashs before...)

I'm just able to show the "dissassembly" where I see my method, but not the C++ code and context !!! But why ?

If someone has an idea to help me to debug this ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Debug symbols for your code? Looks like it doesn't have any symbols cause it's showing only addresses for functions...

Comment: What is strange is that I have "debug symbols" ! I'm able to trace and debug my code without problem, even when I show the "modules" window I see "Symbols loaded" ! Hum... something too big on the stack... possible... but I have no parameter, I start/stop the same thread a lot of time. Also I allocate a buffer of 160 bytes... a lot of times... But before a new allocation I delete the previous one !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time I got this kind of stack and removing code makes it works, it was because I did a ... **stack-overflow** :)

**It's very probable that you have something too big on the stack.**

Check that you don't have a too big object somewhere in a function, often in the main() function. Make sure big objects (managers or things like that) are always allocated on the heap.

Comment: Did you try to see if you didn't have any big object on the stack? I'm almost sure it's the exact problem, but that's from experience : only you can validate or invalidate my answer...

Comment: 1. look at the code that make it work when you remove it, see if one object instantiated there but not on the heap (not using new or malloc) might have a type that's size is big.
2. if nothing is obvious, try a dichotomic search, by spliting the code in two and seeing wich part run until you see wich object breaks the code.

Comment: 3. if you can't find it, try to make sure non-basic types objects are allocated on the heap (maybe using smart pointers like scoped_ptr) just to be sure it's not the problem.
4. you could also simply look at your project settings what is the stack memory size, then add some code to display in a log the size of each type in the faulty code.

Comment: I have found nothing...Finally I think that my stack is corrupted, maybe due to a wrong "memory" operation... but how to detect this ?

Comment: I have even test the soft with "BoundsChecker", but once it crash... it is too late ! This tool is not able to find my memory problem ! Really this drive me crazy !

Comment: I have finally found the problem. It was due to some un-allocated !! I'm not sure of the reason... but it sounds fixed. Thanks for your help ;-)